# Best way to specify "article type" in URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, tags

I'm helping a small blog out that posts a few different "types" of articles. These article types are shared across categories.  We want to put the article type in the URL.  So the structure would look like this:

www.example.com/category/sub-category/article-type/article-name

I'm unsure of the best way to attribute these article types.  Should they be sub-categories (so each category would have a subcategory of "how-to", "interview", "News", etc...

Should I use tags? Can I specify a specific tag to be in a URL (rather than all tags?)

Should I use a custom attribute?

Any guidance is good guidance, i'm at starting point zero...

Comment: Custom Post Type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a way to add article type with tags.

First we add the taxonomy to our post

```
add_action('init', 'article_type_init');

function article_type_init() {
    if (!is_taxonomy('article_type')) {
        register_taxonomy( 'article_type', 'post', 
                   array(   
                        'hierarchical' => FALSE, 
                        'label' => __('Article Type'),  
                        'public' => TRUE, 
                        'show_ui' => TRUE,
                        'query_var' => 'article-type',
                        'rewrite' => true ) );
    }
}
```

Than we hook into the permalink generation, to be sure that we not receive 404 when we will try our new permalink structure

```
add_filter('post_link', 'article_type_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'article_type_permalink', 10, 3);
function rating_article_type($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%article-type%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'article_type');   
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'not-rated'; // add a default tag...

    return str_replace('%article-type%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

Finaly go to your permalink structure (General|Permalink) and change it to :

```
/%article-type%/%postname%
```

And there you go, you're now able to see tags as permalink !

Comment: I think you are confusing `%rating%` and `%article-type%`. Also, the indentation is strange after the first if statement. I agree, using a custom taxonomy is probably the best way to go though.

Comment: @Tspesh does that work ? if yes please approve it, thank you